# Web Api 2 null string get page not found

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

My route is:
[HttpGet]
[Route("General/GetStreetsOfCityByText/{cityCode}/{txt}")]
public IResult GetStreetsOfCityByText(int cityCode, string txt)
{….}
the string txt can be null.
For enabling nullable parameter, I used MapHttpRoute:
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "optionalText",
              routeTemplate: "General/GetStreetsOfCityByText/{cityCode}/{txt}",
              defaults: new { txt = RouteParameter.Optional });
I try to invoke:
http://localhost:56721/General/GetStreetsOfCityByText/3000/
But still gets 404 page not found
I don't get what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Someone showed me a solution:
Add, in the route template, a * befaore the nullable paramter.
Like this:
 [Route("General/GetStreetsOfCityByText/{cityCode}/{*txt}")]
This tells that this parameter may not exist in the invoke URL